# Can we cache images, css and java script in MVC3 through Output Cache?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

Can we cache images, css and javascript of any specific view (not partial view) in MVC3 through OutputCache attribute. like I want to cache my Home Controller view.I tried this but only contents are cached not images and css.

Comment: usually these files are static files. served directly by the web server. are you creating these files dynamic via a controller action? if yes you should be able to just add the attribute.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Yes all these files are static. What i want to do is When there will be no network then i want to show my home page with "System is out of Network" message.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Output Cache attribute you can use following methods to have caching of static resources:

1.Using max-age. Put below section in web.config in  `<configuration>` -> `<system.webServer>` section

```
<staticContent>
    <!-- Tell client to cache static files for a year -->
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"
                 cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

2.Using URL versioning. Can be done by bundling. If you are using MVC3 you could look at [combres on nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/combres/). In MVC4 or above it is build-in option: [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: Hi Garath,I tried with staticContent adding my web.config file but again no luck.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. This web.config statement will enable caching on client side.

Comment: Hi @Garath : After adding the `combres` Nuget, will it start to cache the images/css/js automatically ?

Comment: No. you will have to define bundles

Comment: Hi @Garath: I want to cache my home page and when there is no network connectivity then still i want to show my home page with "System is out of Network" message.

Comment: @Ramesh it is impossible. If your server is down nothing will be shown to user.

Comment: @Garath : After adding the Nuget Package for Combres. Can u tell where to write any code (if any) to Cache the Images/Css/JavaScript files. Please ?

Comment: Look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69484/Combres-2-0-A-Library-for-ASP-NET-Website-Optimiza